# how to make sure the backup data is the same as the data on local machine in linux?

Tags: git, backup, diff

A backup from my git repository is taken on a server. I dont know how the backup script was written and I need to check if it is taking backups correctly or not. So I have to compare the backup data on that server with the data in my local machine.
can I take a copy from the backups on my local machine and then compare them using 'diff' ? Is there a better way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: What is backed up ? Your local `project/` folder ? a copy of some remote repository ?

Comment: a copy of some remote repository

Answer (score 0):

If it's a live Git server, you may find that the diff changes after the backup is made. More importantly, you may find that the data being backed up changes *before* the backup is finished, giving you an internally inconsistent and eventually unusable backup.

If the server is running on a filesystem that can be snapshotted (LVM, etc), snapshot the filesystem first, then make the backup from the snapshot. This is true for all kinds of services.

Depending on the how well you can quiesce services before the snapshot, your backup quality will vary. But at least by using a snapshot, it should be far less internally inconsistent.

To answer your question, once you are sure the data being backed up is not changing as you back it up, a recursive diff should be sufficient to determine if it was persisted properly.

Comment: Thanks. I know that the backup is taken every night using cron job and does not change while backing up as nobody works at that time. can you please tell explain more how to take a copy from whole backup files and compare it with data on my local machine (which is updated from my git repository) ? also i dont know how to use a recursive diff ...

Comment: ```diff -r <dir1> <dir2>```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your backup contains a full copy of the `.git` folder of your repository.

You can compare the commits present in your `project` folder and the commits listed in the `backup` folder by useing the two folders as remotes, and see what is common.

---

detailed instructions :

Say that your working copy is located in `mydir/project_test` :

- get a copy of the backup, which you will store in `mydir/backup`
- go in the `mydir/` directory, and clone your working copy :

  ```
  git clone project_test compare
  ```
- move into the `compare` copy : `cd compare`
- add `backup` as a second remote :

  ```
  git remote add backup ../backup
  ```
- fetch all the commits described in the `backup` copy :

  ```
  git fetch --all
  ```
- from the `compare` repository, `origin` points to your working copy, `backup` points to your backup copy. You can compare the branches :

  ```
  git diff origin/master backup/master
  gitk origin/mybranch backup/mybranch
  tortoise-git origin/master backup/master
  gitk --all  # --all will show you all the branches on both remotes
  etc ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks. while clone I got the this error : `ssh: Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` i am sure the repository exists ...

Comment: What is your local folder's name ?

Comment: how to get a copy of the backup ? it is on a server. then your approach will help me a lot.

Comment: @hketab : can't help you there. Either you have direct access (through ftp, or ssh, ...) to the backup server : copy the files. Or this "backup solution" is completely handled by a third party : ask for a copy.

Comment: yes, I have access through ssh. but i dont know how to make a copy from the server in my local working directory (first step in your solution)? i used `scp SourcePath IpUsername:/DestinationPath` but I get conncetion timeout....